# What license is Google Cloud SDK distributed under?

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

What license is Google Cloud SDK distributed under ? Could not find this clearly mentioned on the documentation page of SDK (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/). Anybody who has installed and used it kindly clarify.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing questions are off-topic

Comment: You may have to read [this](https://github.com/google-cloud-sdk/google-cloud-sdk/blob/master/LICENSE)